# Is there a way to get the name of the current function in vim-script?

Tags: vimscript

Is it possible to programmatically let a function knows its own name?

What I am looking for is something which would allow me to write this code (or something similar):

```
function! myUtils#TestMe() abort
    let l:_self = " a way to get the current function name
    echom l:_self
endfunction
```

Which, once called with `:call myUtils#TestMe()` would print:

```
myUtils#TestMe
```

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33087376/get-the-backtrace-of-a-function-call).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, there is :) Example:

```
function! Testing()
    " this is the droid you're looking for
    echo substitute(expand('<sfile>'), '.*\(\.\.\|\s\)', '', '')
    " compare with this (not what you want, just for reference)
    echo expand('<sfile>')
endfunction

function! OutsideTesting()
    call Testing()
endfunction
```

And the test:

```
:call Testing()
:call OutsideTesting()
```

Surprisingly perhaps, the solution is based on `<sfile>`, which returns something like `function Testing` (if called directly from `Testing`) or `function OutsideTesting..Testing`, if called from the "outer" function. See `:h <sfile>`. The `substitute()` call removes the first part of the expansion and leaves only the inner function name (you can also change the substitution pattern to leave only the outer function name instead - depends on what you want).

Comment: This is amazing! Thank you very much for the detailed answer and for your time.

Comment: This includes the text `function` preceding the function name.

Answer (score 1):

Usage example:

```
function! PrintMyName()
    echomsg 'My name is: ' . FnName()
endfunction

call PrintMyName()
```

Output:

```
My name is: PrintMyName
```

Behind the scenes:

```
" Stacktrace - return array of function names
" Eg, to get calling function name:  Stacktrace(expand('<sfile>'))[0]
" Based on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33094990/5353461
function! Stacktrace(trace)
    return reverse(map(split(substitute(
                \ a:trace,
                \ '^function ', '', ''), '\.\.'),
                \ 'substitute(v:val, ''\m\[\d\+\]$'', "", "")'
            \ )[:-1]) " Remove the sourced file name
endfunction

" The name of the calling function
" Pass parent = 1 to get the parent of the calling function
function! FnName(parent = 0)
  " + 1 because we want to ignore this function itself
  return Stacktrace(expand('<sfile>'))[a:parent + 1]
endfunction
```

It's longer, but more hopefully also more generically useful :)