# Make Lightspeed work with Repmo

Tags: vimscript, cursor-motions, plugin, execute

I'm trying to make the EasyMotion-like (cursor jumping) [Lightspeed](https://github.com/ggandor/lightspeed.nvim) plugin work with [Repmo](https://github.com/Houl/repmo-vim) which repeats a previous motion.

So far, (and after many hours), I've come up with the following:

```
let g:lightspeed_last_motion = ''
augroup lightspeed_last_motion
  autocmd!
  autocmd User LightspeedSxEnter let g:lightspeed_last_motion = 'sx'
  autocmd User LightspeedFtEnter let g:lightspeed_last_motion = 'ft'
augroup end

function! s:LightspeedRepeatMotion(direction) abort
  if index([';', ','], a:direction) < 0
    echomsg 'Invalid direction ' . string(a:direction) . ' passed to ' . FnName()
    return
  endif

  if g:lightspeed_last_motion == 'sx'
    execute "normal \<Plug>Lightspeed_" . a:direction . '_sx'
  else  " Default to ft
    execute "normal \<Plug>Lightspeed_" . a:direction . '_ft'
  endif
endfunction

noremap <Plug>Lightspeed_; :call <SID>LightspeedRepeatMotion(';')<CR>
noremap <Plug>Lightspeed_, :call <SID>LightspeedRepeatMotion(',')<CR>
map  <expr> ; repmo#LastKey("<Plug>Lightspeed_;")|sunmap ;
map  <expr> , repmo#LastRevKey("<Plug>Lightspeed_,")|sunmap ,

map  <expr> s repmo#ZapKey('<Plug>Lightspeed_s')|ounmap s|sunmap s
map  <expr> S repmo#ZapKey('<Plug>Lightspeed_S')|ounmap S|sunmap S
omap <expr> z repmo#ZapKey('<Plug>Lightspeed_s')
omap <expr> Z repmo#ZapKey('<Plug>Lightspeed_S')
map  <expr> f repmo#ZapKey('<Plug>Lightspeed_f')|sunmap f
map  <expr> F repmo#ZapKey('<Plug>Lightspeed_F')|sunmap F
map  <expr> t repmo#ZapKey('<Plug>Lightspeed_t')|sunmap t
map  <expr> T repmo#ZapKey('<Plug>Lightspeed_T')|sunmap T
```

`FnName` is defined [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/5501/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-name-of-the-current-function-in-vim-script/36263#36263).

My problems with the above are:

- When I try to repeat a motion by pressing `;`, I see in the status area:

  - Bottom left: `:call <SNR>3_LightspeedRepeatMotion(';')`
  - Bottom right: `ghtspeed_;`

  I want neither of these to display. My attempt at `silent` didn't work.

  Also, there is a delay, like vim is waiting for another keystroke - the cursor doesn't move immediately.
- It doesn't work in `visual` selection mode. I can't work out how to use `<Cmd>` and still have the mappings work.
- I don't like using global variable `g:lightspeed_last_motion`.  Different buffers should remember their last motion independent of each other.  A simple rename to `b:` doesn't work. How do I achieve this?

Comment: You might use `<silent>` for the mappings for the first bullet. Not sure about the delay or the rest.

Comment: You may also want to try `:help map-<nowait>`. That will fix the "waiting for another keystroke" problem. With proper application of `<silent>` and `<nowait>`, your mappings should work.

Comment: And also just say `:map ;` to see if there are conflicts. Also try adding `<unique>` if you want your scripts to fail if you're worried you're getting hit with this "mapping to a prefix" issue.